# asymptotic approximation ratio vs absolute approximation ratio?

Tags: asymptotics, approximation

I am trying to learn about approximation algorithms. In some research papers, it is mentioned about the absolute approximation ratio. what does the absolute approximation ratio mean? is it different from the asymptotic approximation ratio?

if there is any resource that might help to understand more about this, please leave it here.
Thank you

Comment: I encourage you to [edit] your post to provide context, and in particular, to identify the paper(s) you've been reading that refer to absolute approximation ratio.  It would help to list one or two examples, provide a full reference (title, authors, where published, and if possible, a link to a PDF that is freely available) as well as where in the paper refers to this concept.  Does the paper define this term?  Have you looked through the papers it cites to see if it defines that term?

Comment: You might check from context whether it is the same as the "absolute performance guarantee" from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximation_algorithm

Comment: My guess is that this is the difference between $\alpha \cdot \mathit{OPT}$ and $\alpha \cdot \mathit{OPT} + \beta$.